# How can I find AppID that automatic creat with xcode7

Tags: ios, xcode7, app-id, bundle-identifier

To debug my application with device, I set a bundleID for my application, and xcode7 automatic creat an AppID for it. But I can't find the AppID in developer MemberCenter
My question is, how can I find it and remove it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luhWB.png)ur.com/vbVZZ.png

Answer (score 0):

Look at `Xcode ... Preferences ... Accounts`.  Click on your Apple ID in the left column.  In the right pane, click the `View Details` button.  The AppID should show up as part of the provisioning profile that was used by Xcode for that app.  To delete it, right-click on the profile and chose `Move to Trash`.

Comment: but when I register the same bundleID in Developer,  I  receive errors: "An App ID with Identifier '***' is not available. Please enter a different string."

Comment: How can I login Developer with personal team:

Comment: @Jing have you find the way to fix it? I have the same issue.

Comment: When you get the message that an App ID is not available, that usually means someone else has registered that App ID with Apple.  It's up to you to create an App ID (in the format "com.xxx.yyy") that doesn't generate the "not available" message and register it in the Developer Center. Then, once that App ID is registered, you plug it into your app in the Info section for the project name.